# Crypted drive, rsync and no space on half used drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, rsync, dm-crypt

I have very strange problem that I don't know how to debug further.
Drive is WD 2TB. I use it only for backup of my cloud and server data (lot of small files).

I'm using linux and dm-crypt.. whole disk is without partition and entirely crypted.
I mount it using mount /dev/mapper/crypt ./folder/.

this is my current state with `df -h`

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
....
/dev/mapper/crypt   1.9T  972G  891G  53% /BACKUP
```

rsync just told me there is no more space on drive.

`du -sh /BACKUP/` is confirming space:

```
du -sh /BACKUP/
972G    /BACKUP/
```

Yes, I unmounted forced fsck, even tried to shrink filesystem and all.
Plus + what is most discomforting is that I did

```
cat /dev/urandom >> ddd.dd
```

and it filled whole drive .. 100% .. I deleted some files prior to that. As if it shows full I cannot, it's full.

Some kind of filesystem limit or?

UPDATE:
I cannot add or create files when it says it's full.
But if I delete any small file i can create file of any size, for example:

```
ls /BACKUP/GDRIVE/10\ SHORT\ SIGHTED.mp4 -Alh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12M Aug  1  2015 /BACKUP/*******/10 SHORT SIGHTED.mp4
rm /BACKUP/GDRIVE/10\ SHORT\ SIGHTED.mp4 
echo ddd > dd.dd
cat /dev/urandom >> ddd.dd
-bash: ddd.dd: No space left on device
cat /dev/urandom >> dd.dd
^C
#:/BACKUP# ls -Alh
total 2.8G
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2.8G Mar  5 14:14 dd.dd
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root    4.0K Mar  5 14:12 *******
drwxr-xr-x 30 root nogroup 4.0K Feb 25 15:22 *******
drwx------  2 root root     16K Sep 19 16:03 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4.0K Dec 27 03:09 *******
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    4.0K Jan  2 18:48 *******
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have lots of small files, use `df -i` to check that you are haven't used up all the i-nodes.

If this is is the case there are not many solutions [to dynamically increase the inodes count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem), but I was going to suggest something like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205442/171560), namely create one or more big files in the remaining space that you reformat as disks (with adequate inode count) and mount as loop devices. Maybe you can have these match top directories and so by mounting them adequately you can reproduce the directory structure of your source in several sub-disks.

Comment: I did actually. But this is first time I encounter that problem.. How can I go pass it?

{:/BACKUP# df -iT
Filesystem         Type      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
dev/mapper/crypt2 ext4      476960 476960       0  100% /BACKUP}

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Great answer.. Exactly my thought as I created that big file. So filesystem inside filesystem or reformat with bigger inode table. Uh, Thank you!